# Scrapy - bug in custom DownloaderMiddleware

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

I have list of thousands of `URL` which I scrape using one `Spider`. Some `URL`s has the same domain. I want to count a number of Timeout errors per domain. If for domain x, is a number of Timeouts higher than LIMIT, I want to avoid scraping all `URL`s of this domain. Instead, I want to treat them as it were normal Timeout (without real requesting) - my spider then handle Timeouts in `errback` function.

So the point is that I don't have to keep trying to scrape URLs from domain X if this domain raised 5 Timeouts already. I just want to fake those Timeouts without actually sending requests.

I've created a middleware for this purpose, which seems to be a good way but it has some bugs.

For example, if an `URL` has to be automatically Timeouted (without real request), it seems that scrapy tries to repeat this request multiple times.

LOG:

```
2017-05-22 20:37:16 [engineapp.engine.scrapy.scrapytest.scrapytest.middlewares] INFO: Arbitrary Timeout! OCID: 12751
2017-05-22 20:37:16 [engineapp.engine.scrapy.scrapytest.scrapytest.middlewares] INFO: Arbitrary Timeout! OCID: 12751
2017-05-22 20:37:16 [engineapp.engine.scrapy.scrapytest.scrapytest.middlewares] INFO: Arbitrary Timeout! OCID: 12751
```

Maybe the problem is that I'm not returning anything from `process_request` and `process_exception` functions.

This is the middleware:

```
class TimeoutProcessMiddleware():
    timeouts = defaultdict(int)

    def process_request(self,request, spider):
        logger.debug(self.timeouts)
        occ = request.meta['occ']
        domain = Site.parse_site_from_url(request.url)

        if self.timeouts[domain] >= settings.TIMEOUT_COUNT_LIMIT: # If we detected timeout for more than x URLs with the same domain
            logger.info('Arbitrary Timeout! OCID: {}'.format(occ.id))
            raise TimeoutError()

    def process_exception(self,request, exception, spider):
        logger.debug('Processing exception: EXC: {}'.format(exception))
        if exception.__class__ in [TimeoutError,TCPTimedOutError]:
            domain = Site.parse_site_from_url(request.url)
            self.timeouts[domain]+=1
```

This is a part of Spider errback:

```
class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     ...

     def err(self, failure):
            if failure.check(HttpError):
                ....
            elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError): # HERE I WANT TO PROCESS ALL TIMEOUTS 
                self.process_timeout_error(occ)
```

Do you know what to do?